# Split line at the tab character

Tags: fortran, delimiter

I would like to split a line at tab and read commas as character. I tried to follow a solution of this kind, using a `pos` variable containing "\t" or " ", but it returns me 0, so it doesn't find any tab. Which could be the right solution?

```
INTEGER :: i, dots, commas, A, T, C, G, InDel, M, Z, L, s, sf, numsize, InDelSlide, pos, base, cov
CHARACTER(len=1) :: ref
CHARACTER(len=10000) :: arg, seq, qual
CHARACTER(len=1024) :: buffer
CHARACTER(len=6) :: num
CHARACTER(len=5) chr

READ(5,'(A)') buffer
PRINT *, buffer
pos = INDEX(buffer, "   ")
arg = buffer(1:pos-1)
READ(buffer(pos+1:), *) chr, base, ref, cov, seq, qual
```

Comment: Instead of using an **escaped** representation of a tab ("\t" which I'm not sure it is recognized in Fortran, you can simply use the ASCII value (decimal 9).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tab character in Fotran is simply `achar(9)`. Use

```
pos = INDEX(buffer, achar(9))
```

The `achar()` function returns a character with the ASCII value you pass to it.

Comment: As far as I remember, the tab charcater is ACHAR(9). ACHAR(10) is the "linefeed" character.