# Failed to initialize typeless char in f77

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran77

I tried to assign the horizontal table

```
  character*(*) argz(*),tab*1
  data tab /Z'09'/
```

Compiling with both `f77` and `gfortran` gave

> ```
>    data tab /Z'09'/
>       1 Error: Incompatible types in DATA statement at (1); attempted conversion of INTEGER(16) to CHARACTER(1)
> ```

Comment: See here how to use the `achar` intrinsic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40888582/split-line-at-the-tab-character Do you really need Fortran 77? It is not allowed to assign a BOZ constant to a character.

Comment: Thanks @VladimirF . I solved it by replacing `data ...` with `tab=achar(9)`. I don't want to choose f77 in fact. I'm not familiar with it at all. But I'm making minor change to an existing f77 code, which is too complex for me to reproduce (the math behind the code is terrible).

Comment: @VladimirF   could u make it an answer? I read the manual of `achar` https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/ACHAR.html it doesn't refer `I` is oct or hex. And from the manual of f77, https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/805-4939/c4000413626f/index.html, the `data` statement should work. weird...

Comment: I don't want to make it an answer, if that one suits you I will connect it as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented, if you simply want an ASCII tab character then [`ACHAR(9)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40889342) provides such a thing.  However, there are other aspects to this question which makes it much more general.

A literal constant such as `Z'09'` is known as a BOZ constant. This represents a series of bits.

Use of a BOZ constant is quite restricted in the Fortran standards (becoming less so over time) and many compilers allow other uses beyond the standard as extensions.  For example, a BOZ constant in a Fortran-compliant program may appear in only a small number of places.  Some compilers may allow them to appear any way a literal constant may.

The [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/805-4939/c4000413626f/index.html) you point to in a comment even has that compiler allowing the type of the expression assumed from its use.

With your compilers, trying

```
character tab
data tab /Z'09'/
```

fails.  The gfortran message says that it is taking the constant to be of type `integer(16)` which (correctly) cannot be converted to `character`.  Further, according to the Fortran standard, any data object defined by a BOZ constant in a `data` statement must be an integer.

We know that

```
character :: tab=ACHAR(9)  ! This is also explicit initialization.
```

has the desired effect, but can we do this with a BOZ constant?

You point to the [gfortran documentation of `achar`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/ACHAR.html) and say that it doesn't refer to the argument being hexadecimal.  It says there that `I` must be integer.  A BOZ constant isn't an integer, so `achar(Z'09')` isn't allowed by Fortran.  [Although this is actually accepted by gfortran and other compilers.]

A fully standard compliant approach is

```
character :: tab=ACHAR(INT(Z'09'))
```

as `int` accepts these constants, returning an integer (which is in turn acceptable to `achar`).

---

The constant expression `achar(int(z'09'))` may not itself appear in a `data` statement like

```
character tab
data tab /ACHAR(INT(Z'09'))/  ! No...
```

as it isn't a constant.  However, we could have

```
character, parameter :: tabconst=ACHAR(INT(Z'09'))
character tab
data tab /tabconst/  ! tabconst is a (named) constant
```

Comment: Was `achar()` allowed in initialization expressions in F90 or even F77?

Comment: In F77 certainly not, but in F95 (probably also F90) I believe it was.  However, although `achar(9)` forms an F95 initialization expression, `achar(int(z'9'))` doesn't, because of the restriction on BOZ constants that existed in that standard.

Comment: Detailed so much. Thanks a lot.